# Why do matrices allow for indexing with zero if indexing starts from 1?

Tags: r, matrix

Why does the `matrix` type in R allow for indexing with zero if indexing starts from 1 ?

```
> m = diag(10)
> dim(m[0,0])
[1] 0 0
```

Is this a bug in the language implementation or a feature ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's certainly intentional. From the relevant [section of the R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Indexing-by-vectors):

> All elements of `i` [an integer vector of indices] must have the same sign. If they are positive, the elements of `x` with those index numbers are selected. If `i` contains negative elements, all elements except those indicated are selected.
> ...

> A special case [of using integers to index a vector] is the zero index, which has null effects: `x[0]` is an empty vector and otherwise including zeros among positive or negative indices has the same effect as if they were omitted.

You can argue about whether this is a good idea or not (should including a zero in an integer vector of indices throw an error? Return `NA`? Something else?), but that will rapidly descend into opinion-based territory.